# Cannot connect to blob storage in Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

So I want to create a Copy Data Tool in Azure Data Factory, where I connect to a Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) and copy large amounts data to blob storage. There are five steps you have to go through to set up the copy data tool and I am stuck on number three "Destination"

Destination Screen

[image: 1]

When I test the Connection it works and I created an empty blob storage in my storage account specifically to store my data. When I press the next button I get the error message

`TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'sink')`

For the life of me I don't know why... I tried a new connection with a different name and I tried giving different optional params, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me today. Turns out I skipped selecting the tables in the previous step (source tables). I hit previous, saw a new view of tables that I didn't see before. Picked the tables in the source to move and the error went away.